# Why javadoc is not downloaded in eclipse maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, hive

I created maven project(m2eclipse) in eclipse juno. Project has dependency on hive 0.10 and hadoop 0.23.5.

Maven resolved all dependencies, compiled all ok. 
Now I want to look javadoc and source so I clicke mave-> download javadoc but no reaults.

I also checked maven cache %HOMEPATH%\.m2...\hive-serde\0.10.0\ folder only has compiled jar but no javadoc.

m2e-lastUpdated.properties file has line like this:

```
#Fri May 03 10:30:33 EDT 2013
central|http\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2|javadoc=1367591433214
```

I do not even see an error that javadoc was missing.

By the way I tried

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadJavadocs=true -DdownloadSources=true
```

It did not download anything either and in addition successfully killed my eclipse project since mvn eclipse and m2eclipse are not compatible

Below are exact dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jdo2-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.23.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-serde</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you please post the exact dependencies you're using?

Comment: First of all hadoop 0.23.5 does not exist in maven central on 0.22. and for hive 0.10 there are no sources/javadoc packages available in central.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problems when using Eclipse 4.2 SR2.
My workaround is to call "mvn dependency:sources" on the commandline. It uses the maven-dependency-plugin to do the hard work.
But this only solves the issues for the sources, and not for the javadocs.